# find command skips file

Tags: find

I'm trying to `find` a file, but for some reason it is omitting a directory or a file don't know yet.
If I run this

```
cd ~/Documents/GamesTeam/games/ichristo_dev
find . -name PayoutTest.sh
```

gives

```
./fog/server/source/scripts/PayoutTest.sh
./fog/server/source/bin/templates/PayoutTest.sh
./fog/server/source/target/fog-core-bin/scripts/bin/PayoutTest.sh
```

I take three results, but not the desired one. Instead if I go to a subfolder.

```
cd ~/Documents/GamesTeam/games/ichristo_dev/fog/server/deploy
find . -name PayoutTest.sh
```

gives

```
./bin/PayoutTest.sh
```

It finds an extra one. Why is this happening?

Comment: try option `-L`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a symbolic link to another directory.

What does `ls -l ~/Documents/GamesTeam/games/ichristo_dev/fog/server/deploy` display?

You can use the option `-L` to include directories and files that are linked to, but are not really in that directory tree.

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thanks, I should have thought so.